# Get href within a table

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, href

Sorry, has most likely been asked before but I can't seem to find an answer on stack/from search engine.

I'm trying to scrape some data from a table, but there are href links which I need to get. Html as follows:

```
<table class="featprop results">
<tr>
**1)**<td class="propname" colspan="2"><a href="/lettings-search-results?task=View&amp;itemid=136" rel="nofollow"> West Drayton</a></td>
</tr>
<tr><td class="propimg" colspan="2">

    <div class="imgcrop">
    **2)**<a href="/lettings-search-results?task=View&amp;itemid=136" rel="nofollow"><img src="content/images/1/1/641/w296/858.jpg" alt=" Ashford" width="148"/></a>


    <div class="let">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</td></tr>

<tr><td class="proprooms">
```

So far I have used the following:

```
for table in soup.findAll('table', {'class': 'featprop results'}):
    for tr in table.findAll('tr'):
        for a in tr.findAll('a'):
            print(a)
```

Which returns both 1 and 2 in the above html, could anyone help me strip out just the href link?

Comment: What about `a['href']`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for table in soup.findAll('table', {'class': 'featprop results'}):
    for tr in table.findAll('tr'):
        for a in tr.findAll('a'):
            print(a['href'])
```

out:

```
/lettings-search-results?task=View&itemid=136
/lettings-search-results?task=View&itemid=136
```

[Attributes](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes)

EDIT:

```
links = set() # set will remove the dupilcate
for a in tr.findAll('a', href=re.compile(r'^/lettings-search-results?')):
    links.add(a['href'])
```

[regular expression](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression)

Comment: Thank you! Although this works I am finding some links I don't want, is is possible to only return links which start with '/lettings-search-results?'

Comment: This worked but returned 3 of each of the links. So I need to work on removing the duplicates. Thank you!

Comment: @Maverick put all the links in a set(), this will remove duplicate.

Comment: Struggling to add this to a set, would you be able to show me what you mean please?

Answer (score 1):

This provide you an array of  tags under the element of the selected class name.

```
result = soup.select(".featprop a");
for a in result:
    print(a['href'])
```

Give you the below result:

```
/lettings-search-results?task=View&itemid=136
/lettings-search-results?task=View&itemid=136
```